# An $m$ coloured graph must have a path with each vertex taking up one colour each

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

> Suppose that the chromatic number of graph $G$ is $m$ and $c\colon \operatorname{V}(G) \to \{1,2,3,\dotsc,m\}$ is a proper $m$-coloring of $G$. Then must there be a path $x_1, \dotsc, x_m$ in $G$ with $c(x_i) = i$ ?

After trying many examples, I think the answer is a yes. However I am finding it difficult to actually prove it. Is a proof by contradiction a good way to start this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will prove a slight generalization: if $\chi(G)=m$ and if $c:V(G)\to\mathbb N$ is a proper coloring of $G,$ then there is a path $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m$ in $G$ with $c(x_1)\lt c(x_2)\lt\cdots\lt c(x_m).$ Of course, if the range of $c$ is $\{1,2,\dots,m\},$ then we must have $c(x_i)=i$ for each $i.$

For $x\in V(G),$ let $\ell(x)$ be the greatest integer $\ell$ for which there is a path $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_\ell$ in $G$ with $c(x_1)\lt c(x_2)\lt\cdots\lt c(x_\ell)$ and $x_1=x.$ Clearly, if $xy\in E(G)$ and $c(x)\lt c(y),$ then $\ell(x)\gt\ell(y).$ Hence $\ell:V(G)\to\mathbb N$ is a proper coloring of $G.$ Since $\chi(G)=m,$ there must be a vertex $x\in V(G)$ with $\ell(x)\ge m,$ and so there is a path $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m$ in $G$ with $c(x_1)\lt c(x_2)\lt\cdots\lt c(x_m).$