# Proving "A graph $G$ with chromatic number $$ has a proper coloring with a walk with $k$ vertices in $k$ different colors" by induction

Tags: graph-theory, induction, coloring

I'm trying to prove "A graph $G$ with the chromatic number $$ has a proper coloring with a walk with $k$ vertices in $k$ different colors".

I tried using induction to prove this statement such as color the graph, remove edges to change it into a $(k-1)$-colorable graph, and then connect the $(k-1)$-walk with one deleted edge. From here on I'm not sure how to proceed to connect the walk, especially about how to ensure I can find such a vertex to connect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need the graph to be connected besides being k-colorable, right?

Comment: To me, a graph with $n$ vertices is always $n$-colorable. Then this would mean that every graph has a Hamiltonian path... Maybe you need additional conditions ?

Where does this idea come from ?

Comment: This should be true if we change the condition from "$k$-colorable" to "has chromatic number $k$".

Comment: @HugoManet A walk can repeat vertices, a path can't, so this property isn't equivalent to what you say, unless I'm misreading you.

Comment: Oh, if "a walk with $k$ vertices" mean "a walk with $k$ different vertices" then yeah. Else, since every vertex has a different color, they can't repeat.

Anyway, to me a graph with $n$ vertices is also $(n+1)$ colorable, which should settle the matter. ^^

Comment: Sorry I should change the condition to "has chromatic number " as @MishaLavrov said and it might help clarify the connectivity of the graph.

Comment: @bof Yes I think it answers my question. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among all proper colorings $f:V(G)\to\{1,2,3,\dots,k\}$, choose one which maximizes the sum $\sum_{v\in V(G)}f(v)$. Then each vertex $v$ with $f(v)\lt k$ has a neighbor $w$ with $f(w)=f(v)+1$, as otherwise we could increase that sum by changing the color of $v$. Hence we can construct a path $v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots,v_k$ with $f(v_i)=i$ for each $i$.

**P.S.** In fact, if $\chi(G)=k$, then for **any** proper coloring $f:V(G)\to\{1,2,3,\dots,k\}$ there is a path $v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots,v_k$ with $f(v_i)=i$ for each $i$; see the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990260/an-m-coloured-graph-must-have-a-path-with-each-vertex-taking-up-one-colour-eac).